# Present participle: "happening"

Tags: sentence-construction

> As a vital organ plays a critical role in most metabolic processes
>   **happening** in the body, liver also takes part in other modulations.

I am a new English learner. This is a sentence I have written. I am not confident in using "happening" as a present participle here? If I want to make it appear to be more academic and professional (more complex), what verb can I use to substitute "happening" here?

Thank you!

Comment: The word you're looking for is "occurring." But honestly, "happening" is not the worst choice. Meanwhile, there are a few other mistakes in your sentence I would watch out for. Lastly, if you want, you could also just take out happening and just say, "...in many of the metabolic processes of the body...."

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang Could you please tell me the "other mistakes" you mentioned in this sentence?

Comment: Alternative 1 : As a vital organ that plays a critical role in most metabolic processes that occur in the body, the liver also takes part in other modulations. Alternative 2: As a vital organ that plays a critical role in most metabolic processes occurring in the body, the liver also takes part in other modulations.

Comment: Does **modulation** have some special meaning in the context of biochemistry? If not, it's usage here is meaningless.

Comment: **as** at the beginning of a sentence normally means because, but that doesn't make sense in this sentence. It would be better the liver to the beginning: "The liver [is a vital organ and] plays a critical role in most metabolic processes in the body. The liver also takes part in ????".